# Javascript Popup Functions

Tags: javascript, popup, modal-dialog

I have a javascript function to show a hidden element and position it on the center of the screen. I want to also have it re-position itself if the window is resized. Here is what I have so far:

```
function togglePopup(element, screen, position) {
element = document.getElementById(element);
if (element.style.display === '') {
    element.style.display = 'block';
    if (screen === true) {
        document.getElementById('screen').style.display = 'block';
    }
    if (position === true) {
        positionPopup(element);
        window.onresize = positionPopup(element);
    }
} else {
    element.style.display = '';
    if (screen === true) {
        document.getElementById('screen').style.display = '';
    }
}
```

return false;
}

So the function takes the ID of an element and whether there is a screen behind it and if it is going to be positioned on the screen. If it is going to be positioned, I need to have it re-position on window.onresize but that doesn't seem to be working. How can I do this properly?

Comment: I would recommend that you position it with CSS.

Comment: I just looked into this further and fixed positioning should work. Javascript just needs to set negative margins.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to reinvent the wheel, take a look on this:

http://jqueryui.com/dialog/

Comment: I didn't design the site and it has some other javascript library that is preventing jQuery from working properly, so I am looking for a javascript fix.